# MongoDB and python increment a value failing

Tags: python, mongodb

I am getting the object but when I try to increment an int32 value of a key using update it doesn't update - but page still loads. I have tried a number of different ways to do this but nothing seems to work.

```
 @app.route('/recipe/<recipe_id>')
def recipe(recipe_id):
    recipe_db = mongo.db.recipes.find_one_or_404({'_id': ObjectId(recipe_id)})
    # print(recipe_db)
    # new_view_amount = recipe_db['views']
    # print(new_view_amount)
    recipe_db.update({'$inc': {'views': 1}})
    return render_template('recipe.html', recipe=recipe_db)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question if anyone comes across this I used:

```
mongo.db.recipes.find_one_and_update(
        {'_id': ObjectId(recipe_id)},
        {'$inc': {'views': 1}}
    )
```